# Setting innerHTML on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, prototypejs

I am setting the innerHTML property of document element within this way:

```
document.getElementById('some_element').innerHTML = newHTML;
```

And this works fine in web browser on desktop and on iPhone simulator. But on iPhone device this works good randomly. I mean, sometimes works, sometimes does not. One proposed solution from google groups is to try to repeat this function call about 20 times with 50 ms pause between. Come on. Is there some logical explanation about that mysterious delay?

Here are the links for this issue on google groups:

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/0d24a9fda0921407#

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/a5787985293b6de1/8d826c8506377025?lnk=gst&q=innerHTML#8d826c8506377025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When* is that code called?

I guess if this code is called when the document is loadead, like onLoad(), the DOM might not have loaded completely yet.

Personally for these kind of things I simply include jQuery and do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#some_element').html(newHTML);
  } );
</script>
```

... or in Prototype:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
    // do yo thang...
});
```

This ensures that the DOM is completely loaded before the script fires; thus avoiding this kind of race condition.

To include jQuery, just download it from their [official website](http://jquery.org/) and drop it in your Xcode project. Alternatively, if your HTML document is served via HTTP, you can just drop it next to the HTML file on the server.

Oh, and before I forget it. The code that loads my HTML file from the project looks like this:

```
NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myHtmlFile" 
                                         withExtension:@"html"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note, I am beginner with javascript and I am using only prototype.js. This function call surely executes after the 'dom:loaded' is fired once at start-up.

Comment: But I suppose you are right. Is there some similar function like document.ready in prototype.js?

Comment: See updated answer above. :)
Never used Prototype, but your problem definitely sounds like a race condition. Oh, and make sure you don't load any external JS files/execute any other JS code *before* the handler function.